# Troubles importing Python modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

please, I need some help with the following.

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.7, VSCode 1.32 and I also have installed the current version of Anaconda (and its package).

When I want to import a module from a code written in VSCode, say *fileName.py* file, such as `import flask`, I get a DLL ImportError saying that the module can't be found.

When I try to do the same from Spyder (python IDE) I have no problems (which means that I have the modules installed).

In my Path variables I have:
[all this list, and the Anaconda folder among others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHyxs.jpg)

and, in the **terminal**, the error exactly says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "py_test.py", line 1, in < module >
>
> import flask
>
> File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask__init__.py", line > 21, in < module >
>
> from .app import Flask, Request, Response
>
> File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 25, 
>   in < module >
>
> from . import cli, json
>
> File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 18, >in < module >
>
> import ssl
>
> File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in < module >
>
> import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Please, I need to be able to import it from VSCode, I can't just turnaround it using Spyder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why it is not about software? VSCode is a software, and my question is about what to do in order to get VSCode working as expected when importing modules. I'm not asking how to import them (I'm saying that I know how to do it) is just that I need help to set VSCode to find the modules that are working correctly in another software (Spyder IDE). Please explain.